# I ran ChkRootkit and came up with a infected file. I need help

Tags: chkrootkit

So I ran a `chkrootkit`. I have `linux.xor.ddos` showing as infected. I read other forums online and I have seen things mentioning false positives. What is `linux.xor.ddos` file and how can I check if they are fine?

Comment: Where is the file located? What is its name? We need more information.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what linux.xor.ddos files are, how would I be able to locate it?

Comment: I thought chkrootkit would have told you. However, a bit of googling showed that chkrootkit reports any binary that's in /tmp as linux.xor.ddos. Check and see what is in that directory.

Comment: So Linux.xor.ddos is malware, should I remove this vpn, or is this common to happen?

Comment: A VPN shouldn't really install in to /tmp. What VPN are you using?

Comment: Private Internet Access. PIA

Comment: Use the PIA OpenVPN configs with Ubuntu's built in VPN client.

Comment: Ok I will try that. I installed it as a program and it runs outside of the built in VPN client. I followed the instructions from their homepage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binaries in `/tmp` are flagged as "linux.xor.ddos" regardless of if they're infected or not. This was the case with the poster.

Answer (score 3):

Any file under temporary folder marked as executable will raise a flag.

```
enigma@t495:/tmp$ touch virus
enigma@t495:/tmp$ chmod +x virus
enigma@t495:/tmp$ sudo chkrootkit
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ... INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
/tmp/virus
```