# Chkrootkit results, how to reinstall tpcd ?

Tags: chkrootkit

I run chkrootkit and these were the results.

```
Checking `tcpd'...                                          INFECTED
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...                            INFECTED: 
Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
/tmp/timeshift/WwbV62M9/2018-22-12_10-00-02/script.sh
/tmp/timeshift/rPVBQw24/2018-21-12_08-00-02/script.sh
/tmp/timeshift/ICt8w9QP/2018-23-12_10-00-02/script.sh
/tmp/timeshift/Gi32umT0/2018-23-12_09-00-01/script.sh
```

Then for

```
sudo sha1sum /usr/sbin/tcpd
```

Result is: (which seems infected)

```
9ee346a9400f52e16576db35c310a72af391e199  /usr/sbin/tcpd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chkrootkit shows "tcpd" as INFECTED. Is it a false positive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883495/chkrootkit-shows-tcpd-as-infected-is-it-a-false-positive)

Answer (score 0):

Very likely a false positive - check out this question:
[chkrootkit shows "tcpd" as INFECTED. Is it a false positive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883495/chkrootkit-shows-tcpd-as-infected-is-it-a-false-positive)

Same for the other hit you got:
[I ran ChkRootkit and came up with a infected file. I need help.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086572/i-ran-chkrootkit-and-came-up-with-a-infected-file-i-need-help)

On my system it also flags tcpd as Infected although I don't even have it installed.